# JPA criteria, where count > 0

Tags: jpa, criteria, jpa-2.1

I have 2 tables:

- Client
- Invoice

Client has an OneToMany association, to list the invoices.

I want to use CriteriaBuilder to create this select:

```
select 
   ... 
from 
  Client c 
where 
  (select count(1) from Invoice i where i.id = c.invoiceId) > 0
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `JPQL` you can use :

```
Query query = em.createQuery
 ("SELECT c FROM Client c WHERE (SELECT COUNT(i) FROM Invoice i WHERE i.client= c) > 0");
List<Client> clientc=query.getResultList());
```

but with `Criteria API` as you are using `subquery` in `where clause` you need something like below (maybe it's not exactly what you want I'm not sure because didn't test I just write it):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();  
CriteriaQuery<Client> q = cb.createQuery(Client.class); 
Root<Client> client =  q.from(Client.class); 
q.select(client);

Subquery<Invoice> sq= q.subquery(Invoice.class); 
Root<Invoice> invoice= sq.from(Invoice.class);  
sq.select(invoice);

Predicate sqp = cb.equal(client.get("id"), invoice.get("invoiceId"));
sq.where(sqp);
q.where(cb.exists(sq));
```